# Is there introduce variable function for PHP in Intellij?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, code-completion

I remember I used "*introduce variable*" feature back in the days in [php](/questions/tagged/php). Maybe it was [[image]phpstorm](/questions/tagged/phpstorm) (don't remember) but it was definitely PHP.

Now I can use the feature only in [java](/questions/tagged/java) (and possibly other languages) but not in PHP. Not even as a postfix code completion `new Object().var` + [TAB] key - which is also possible for Java.

Comment: added tags and formatted the question

Comment: Intellij Idea 2016.3.2 and it is still not there in the PHP plugin :(( so annoying - wonder why did they ever remove it at first place, I remember I was using it in PHP too. You can check the settings, just search for 'introduce local variable' it will find it for java but in the PHP section you do not have this option. Did you find any solution? it seems there are no plugins for this either